# How to link to a macro-enabled Excel file from an Access Unbound Objectframe

Tags: excel, ms-access, macros, ms-access-2016, ole

I want to link a "TimePicker" housed on an Excel macro enabled spreadsheet (it has three textboxes for hrs, min, AM/PM with associated SpinnerButtons [SBs] operating with SB_Change events code) to an unbound Objectframe (OLE1) of an Access form. The user will select the time settings which will then be transferred to the appropriate Access form textbox. I'm using a command button click routine to perform the link to the Objectframe. Ideally I would like to use the TimePicker within OLE1. On running the code the textboxes appear in OLE1, but not the SBs. Also the code quits running as soon as it hits the .Action line.
I like the idea of using the OLE1 object, but it is such a "black box" with all the different properties specified with only strings. What am I missing? Thank you for any and all suggestions.  The code:

```
Private Sub GetTimePicker_Click()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim obOLE1 As ObjectFrame

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(" [filepath] \TimePicker2.xlsm") ' specify file
Set obOLE1 = Me.OLE1
xlApp.Visible = True
With obOLE1
    .SourceDoc = " [filepath] /TimePicker2.xlsm"
    .Class = "Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12"
    .OLETypeAllowed = acOLEEither
    .AutoActivate = 0  'vbOLEActivateManual
    .SetFocus
    .SourceItem = "Shapes.Range(Array('txtHr', 'txtMin', 'txtAPM', 'SP1', 'SP2', 'SP3', 'Label1'))"
    .Verb = acOLEVerbOpen
    .Action = acOLELinked
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead and overkill for just collecting time. Why not just build your collection boxes in Access with dropdowns?

Comment: This was my first try at using an OLE object frame and on a whim I thought it would be a nifty way of inputting a time stamp using the SpinnerButton feature of Excel.  However, I definitely agree with you now that I've learned more about the object frames various properties.  So... is it worth it for future reference.... Is it not possible to manipulate macro enabled features of Excel through this Object Frame?  If it is, what are the key properties to set that would make this possible?  I thought perhaps setting the SourceItem property to the actual Active X elements would help.